# convert input time zone based on associated records zone field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a bus_stops table with a one to one association with address table and address has a time zone attribute.

Now when searching for stop timings, say all buses departing on 7 PM, this has to search for stops with buses departing on local time 7 PM, ie,

for each bus_stop, I need to convert 7PM into local time zone of the bus stop depending on the time zone on address record.

How would I achieve this using SQL (for postgres)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is not very specific, I'll answer with an example how something like that chould be done. You'll have to adapt the example for your  purposes; for example, I don't expect that you store departure times as `timestamp with time zone`.

```
CREATE TABLE address (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   timezone text NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO address VALUES
   (1, 'America/Los_Angeles'),
   (2, 'America/Chihuahua');

CREATE TABLE bus_stop (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   depart TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
   address_id INTEGER NOT NULL
      REFERENCES address(id)
);

INSERT INTO bus_stop VALUES
   (1, '2017-06-27 19:00:00 America/Los_Angeles', 1),
   (2, '2017-06-27 18:00:00 America/Los_Angeles', 1),
   (3, '2017-06-27 18:00:00 America/Los_Angeles', 2);
```

Now we want to know at which bus stops there will be a bus departing at 19:00 local time:

```
SELECT b.id
FROM bus_stop b
   JOIN address a
      ON b.address_id = a.id
WHERE (b.depart AT TIME ZONE a.timezone) = TIMESTAMP '2017-06-27 19:00:00';

┌────┐
│ id │
├────┤
│  1 │
│  3 │
└────┘
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `AT TIME ZONE` to convert from a timezone to another:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40' AT TIME ZONE 'MST';
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40' AT TIME ZONE 'BRT';
```

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html).